# LoRa recieves only 2-4 packets, then stops working

Tags: arduino-mega, error, lora

I'm working on LoRa project using [Ai-Thinker RA-01 SX1278 433MHz LoRa][1] with [sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa][2] library. I modified LoRaReciever example so it looks like this

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  LoRa.onReceive(onReceive);
}
void onReceive(int packetSize) {
  
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet '");

    // read packet
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
    }

    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  }
}
```

I receive 2-4 packets successfully, but then I don't receive any, even though the transmitter is still transmitting. (If I restart my Arduino it receives 2-4 packets again).

I have both LoRa modules really close to each other (about 10 cm) could it cause the problem? - Even when I tried like 15m with walls, problem stayed.

Sometimes, the receiver gets bugged and starts receiving packets all the time (one packet like 50 times), when it's bugged like this, it doesn't stop receiving (unique) packets after any number.

Do you know where the problem could be? Thanks.

I use Arduino Mega

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  if (!LoRa.begin(915E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet '");

    // read packet
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
    }

    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  }
}
```

This is original LoRaReciever example, but I don't receive anything using it.
[1]: https://www.laskarduino.cz/ai-thinker-ra-01-sx1278-433mhz-lora-modul/
[2]: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa

Comment: start with the example code ... it seems that you made questionable changes to the example code

Comment: When using the default example code, I don’t get anything recieved at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was with calling `onRecieve` in `loop` not in `setup`
It should have looked like this...

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  LoRa.onReceive(onReceive);
  LoRa.receive();
}

void loop() {
  //do nothing
}
void onReceive(int packetSize) {
  
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet '");

    // read packet
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
    }

    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  }
}
```